# Adding rows as objects to the key and sending to backend using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter

I've been trying to add new rows and when I click on save button at the bottom the row. Values like order,input1,input2, checkbox( if its selected) should be added as each individual objects to the "overallData" inside the "queryparam". So, If I create 3 new rows then it should add 3 objects to the "overallData" array and send to the axios post. I tried to push it in a new array and tried to get it using map it didn't work. Is there any way to do it?

https://codesandbox.io/s/add-remove-items-p42xr?file=/src/App.js:817-827

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemnted all the logic you want in this code. Now it works like a charm. Dynamially add new form fields. Provide them value. When you click on save button, only the checked ones are submitted. A few thing to mention:

1).In order to meet the program requirements, I changed the default values for a new form to `{ orderno: 0, inputValue1: "", inputValue2: "", checked: false }`.

2).I added a new state `orderNumber` to control order numbers efficiently

3).When you click the save button the unchecked forms are filtered out.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const App = () => {

  const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState([
    { orderno: 0, inputValue1: "", inputValue2: "", checked: false }
  ]);

  // control order number in a state to make sure
  // that it does not get messed when you remove
  // an indice from formValues
  // !! default was 0. so set it to 1
  const [orderNumber, setOrderNumber] = useState(1)


  const addFormFields = () => {
    setFormValues(prevState => [
      ...prevState,
      {
        orderno: orderNumber,
        inputValue1: '', 
        inputValue2: '', 
        checked: false 
      }
    ]);
    // increment order number
    setOrderNumber(prev => prev+1)
  };


  const removeFormFields = (i) => {
    let newFormValues = [...formValues];
    newFormValues.splice(i, 1);

    setFormValues(newFormValues);

    // decrement order number
    setOrderNumber(prev => prev-1)
  };


  const onChangeFieldValue = (index, key, value) => {
    setFormValues(prevState => {
      let copyState = [...prevState]

      if(value === 'toggle') // toggle 'checked' key
        copyState[index][key] = !copyState[index][key]
      else
        copyState[index][key] = value

      return copyState
    })
  }

  const saveFields = (e) => {
    const queryparam = {
      data: "xxx",
      DbData: "xxx",
      SQlData: "xxx", // only checked ones
      overallData: formValues.filter(el => el.checked)
    };
    console.log(queryparam)
    //axios.post('..',queryparam)
  };
  return (
    <>
      {formValues.length <= 4
        ? formValues.map((element, index) => (
            <div className="form-inline" key={index}>
              <label>{index + 1}</label>

              <input
                type="text"
                value={element.inputVal1}
                onChange={(e) => onChangeFieldValue(index, 'inputValue1', e.target.value)}
              />
              <input
                type="text"
                value={element.inputVal2}
                onChange={(e) => onChangeFieldValue(index, 'inputValue2', e.target.value)}
              />
              <input 
                type="checkbox"
                checked={element.checked}
                onChange={(e) => onChangeFieldValue(index, 'checked', 'toggle')}/>
              <button
                className="button add"
                type="button"
                onClick={() => addFormFields()}
              >
                Add
              </button>

              <button
                type="button"
                className="button remove"
                onClick={() => removeFormFields(index)}
              >
                Remove
              </button>
            </div>
          ))
        : ""}
      <button
        type="button"
        className="button remove"
        onClick={(e) => saveFields(e)}
      >
        Save
      </button>
      <button
        type="button"
        className="button remove"
        onClick={(e) => cancelFields(e)}
      >
        cancel
      </button>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: I don't need the data which is checked as I need to pass whether it is checked or not to the backend. I need all the row added with inputs and checkbox value. I've removed the filter condition and it worked. Thank you :)

Comment: is there any way we can add checkboxs for each row and get its value? like for the second row it will have 1 check box  as value 1 and for 3rd row it will have 2 checkboxs as value 1 ,2 etc and so on. When I click on save the rows added will have its corresponding checked box value too. https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-rgb-lc034?file=/src/App.js